# Error: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: La instrucción no devolvió un conjunto de resultados

Tags: java, sql-server, netbeans

Hola tengo un problema a la hora de hacer una transacción en Java con SQL Server, esa información del insert que hace la transacción la quiero mostrar en tabla pero me aparece el error

> Error: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: La instrucción no devolvió un conjunto de resultados.

Lo que debe mostrar es el resultado en una tabla de todos los cálculos.

Este es el código de botón que ejecuta la transacción

```java
    String sql = "";
    //bloque try
    try {
        //cargamos los datos del formulario
        DefaultTableModel modelo = new DefaultTableModel();
        jtTransaccion.setModel(modelo);
    
        Conexion_Nomina con;
        con = new Conexion_Nomina();                       //Conexion
        Conectaron cnx = con.getConnection();
    
        //intruccion para Transaccion
        sql = "begin try\n"
                + " begin transaction Nomina\n"
                + " \n"
                + "--Decalar las varibles\n"
                + "-- 
        ********************************************************************************\n"
                + "     declare @RFC varchar(15),\n"
                + "         @NOMBRE varchar(30),\n"
                + "         @F_INGRESO date,\n"
                + "         @ID_PUESTO int,\n"
                + "         @ID_OFICINA int,\n"
                + "         @ID_DTO int,\n"
                + "         @ID_SUBD int,\n"
                + "         @S_DIARIO money,\n"
                + "         @DIAS_T_QNA int,\n"
                + "         @H_EXT int,\n"
                + "         @T_S_QNA money,\n"
                + "         @T_H_EXTRAS money,\n"
                + "         @T_CANASTA money,\n"
                + "         @T_P_VAC MONEY,\n"
                + "         @T_P_DOM money,\n"
                + "         @T_AGUINALDO money,\n"
                + "         @T_R_UTILIDAD money,\n"
                + "         @T_D_FEST money,\n"
                + "         @T_BONO_PRODUCTIVIDAD money,\n"
                + "         @T_OTROS_BONO1 money,\n"
                + "         @T_OTROS_BONO2 money,\n"
                + "         @T_OTROS_BONO3 money,\n"
                + "         @T_ISPT money,\n"
                + "         @T_ISSSTE money,\n"
                + "         @T_FOVISSTE MONEY,\n"
                + "         @T_C_SINDICAL MONEY,\n"
                + "         @T_PRESTAMO_INDIVIDUAL MONEY,\n"
                + "         @T_OTROS_DEDU1 MONEY,\n"
                + "         @T_OTROS_DEDU2 MONEY,\n"
                + "         @T_OTROS_DEDU3 MONEY,\n"
                + "         @T_PERCEP MONEY,\n"
                + "         @T_DED MONEY,\n"
                + "         @T_LIQUIDO MONEY,\n"
                + "         @ESTADO int\n"
                + "     set @RFC = (select RFC from DATOS_GEN where RFC = 
                'AGDI850904TP1');\n"
                + "     set @NOMBRE = (select NOMBRE from DATOS_GEN where RFC = @RFC);\n"
                + "     set @F_INGRESO = (select F_INGRESO from DATOS_GEN where RFC = 
                @RFC);\n"
                + "     set @ID_PUESTO = (select ID_PUESTO from DATOS_GEN where RFC = 
                @RFC);\n"
                + "     set @ID_OFICINA = (select ID_OFICINA from DATOS_GEN where RFC = 
                @RFC);\n"
                + "     set @ID_DTO = (select ID_DPTO from DATOS_GEN where RFC = @RFC);\n"
                + "     set @ID_SUBD = (select ID_SUBD from DATOS_GEN where RFC = @RFC);\n"
                + "     set @S_DIARIO = (select S_DIARIO from DATOS_GEN where RFC = 
                @RFC);\n"
                + "     set @DIAS_T_QNA = (select DIAS_T_QNA from DATOS_GEN where RFC = 
                @RFC);\n"
                + "     set @H_EXT = (select H_EXTRAS from DATOS_GEN where RFC = @RFC);\n"
                + "     set @T_S_QNA  = 0;\n"
                + "     set @T_H_EXTRAS = 0;\n"
                + "     set @T_CANASTA = 0;\n"
                + "     set @T_P_VAC = 0;\n"
                + "     set @T_P_DOM = 0;\n"
                + "     set @T_AGUINALDO = 0;\n"
                + "     set @T_R_UTILIDAD = 0;\n"
                + "     set @T_D_FEST = 0;\n"
                + "     set @T_BONO_PRODUCTIVIDAD = 0;\n"
                + "     set @T_OTROS_BONO1 = 0;\n"
                + "     set @T_OTROS_BONO2 = 0;\n"
                + "     set @T_OTROS_BONO3 = 0;\n"
                + "     set @T_ISPT = 0;\n"
                + "     set @T_ISSSTE = 0;\n"
                + "     set @T_FOVISSTE = 0;\n"
                + "     set @T_C_SINDICAL = 0;\n"
                + "     set @T_PRESTAMO_INDIVIDUAL = 0;\n"
                + "     set @T_OTROS_DEDU1 = 0;\n"
                + "     set @T_OTROS_DEDU2 = 0;\n"
                + "     set @T_OTROS_DEDU3 = 0;\n"
                + "     set @T_PERCEP = 0;\n"
                + "     set @T_DED = 0;\n"
                + "     set @T_LIQUIDO = 0;\n"
                + "     set @ESTADO = (select ESTADO from DATOS_GEN where RFC = @RFC);\n"
                + "     \n"
                + "\n"
                + "-- 
********************************************************************************\n"
                + "\n"
                + "--Iniciar con los calculos\n"
                + "--********************************************************************************\n"
                + " if @ESTADO = 1\n"
                + "     begin\n"
                + "         --  Calcular el Sueldo quincenal T_S_QNA = sueldo diario por  
                días trabajados en la quincena\n"
                + "         set @T_S_QNA = (@S_DIARIO * @DIAS_T_QNA);\n"
                + "\n"
                + "         --  Calcular las horas extras T_H_EXTRAS = sueldo diario / 8 *2* 
                No. de horas extras\n"
                + "         set @T_H_EXTRAS = ((@S_DIARIO / 8) * 2 * @H_EXT);\n"
                + "\n"
                + "         --  Calcular la prima vacacional Si PRIMA_VAC = 1  entonces 
                T_P_VAC = 15 * sueldo diario\n"
                + "         if(select PRIMA_VAC from DATOS_GEN where RFC = @RFC) = 1\n"
                + "             begin\n"
                + "                 set @T_P_VAC = (15 * @S_DIARIO);\n"
                + "             end\n"
                + "         --  Calcular el ISR  T_ISPT = 20% de la suma de T_S_QNA + 
                T_H_EXTRAS + T_P_VAC\n"
                + "         set @T_ISPT = (@T_S_QNA + @T_H_EXTRAS + @T_P_VAC) * .20;\n"
                + "\n"
                + "         --  Calcular el total de percepciones  T_PERCEP es la suma de 
                T_S_QNA + T_H_EXTRAS + T_P_VAC\n"
                + "         set @T_PERCEP = ((@T_S_QNA) + (@T_H_EXTRAS) + (@T_P_VAC));\n"
                + "\n"
                + "         --  Calcular el total de deducciones T_DED  = T_ISPT\n"
                + "         set @T_DED = (@T_ISPT);\n"
                + "\n"
                + "         --  Calcular el total líquido  T_LIQUIDO=  Total percepciones – 
                Total deducciones\n"
                + "         set @T_LIQUIDO = (@T_PERCEP - @T_DED);\n"
                + "     end\n"
                + "--********************************************************************************\n"
                + "\n"
                + "\n"
                + "--insertar los valores en la tabla ARCH_QUINZ\n"
                + "     insert into ARCH_QUINZ values (@RFC,@NOMBRE,@F_INGRESO,@ID_PUESTO,@ID_OFICINA,@ID_DTO,@ID_SUBD,@S_DIARIO,\n"
                + "     @DIAS_T_QNA,@H_EXT,@T_S_QNA,@T_H_EXTRAS,@T_CANASTA,@T_P_VAC,@T_P_DOM,@T_AGUINALDO,@T_R_UTILIDAD,@T_D_FEST,\n"
                + "     @T_BONO_PRODUCTIVIDAD,@T_OTROS_BONO1,@T_OTROS_BONO2,@T_OTROS_BONO3,@T_ISPT,@T_ISSSTE,@T_FOVISSTE,@T_C_SINDICAL,\n"
                + "     @T_PRESTAMO_INDIVIDUAL,@T_OTROS_DEDU1,@T_OTROS_DEDU2,@T_OTROS_DEDU3,@T_PERCEP,@T_DED,@T_LIQUIDO)\n"
                + "\n"
                + " commit transaction Nomina\n"
                + " \n"
                + " end try\n"
                + " begin catch \n"
                + "     --codigo para mostrar el mensjae de la excepcion\n"
                + "     \n"
                + "     rollback transaction Nomina\n"
                + " end catch";
    
        PreparedStatement pst = cnx.prepareStatement(sql); //Crear el statement
        ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery(); //Linea para ejecuar la consulta.
        ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData(); //Linea para mostrar los datos.
        int cantidadColumnas = rsmd.getColumnCount(); //Numero de columnas que vamos a tener
    
        modelo.addColumn("RFC");
        modelo.addColumn("NOMBRE");
        modelo.addColumn("F_INGRESO");
        modelo.addColumn("ID_PUESTO");
        modelo.addColumn("ID_OFICINA");
        modelo.addColumn("ID_DTPO");
        modelo.addColumn("ID_SUBD");
        modelo.addColumn("S_DIARIO");
        modelo.addColumn("DIAS_T_QNA");
        modelo.addColumn("H_EXTRAS");
        modelo.addColumn("T_S_QNA");
        modelo.addColumn("T_H_EXTRAS");
        modelo.addColumn("T_CANASTA");
        modelo.addColumn("T_P_VAC");
        modelo.addColumn("T_P_DOM");
        modelo.addColumn("T_AGUINALDO");
        modelo.addColumn("T_R_UTILIDAD");
        modelo.addColumn("T_D_FEST");
        modelo.addColumn("T_BONO_PRODUCTIVIDAD");
        modelo.addColumn("T_OTROS_BONOS1");
        modelo.addColumn("T_OTROS_BONOS2");
        modelo.addColumn("T_OTROS_BONOS3");
        modelo.addColumn("T_ISP");
        modelo.addColumn("T_ISSSTE");
        modelo.addColumn("T_FOVISTE");
        modelo.addColumn("T_C_SINDICAL");
        modelo.addColumn("T_PRESTAMO_INDIVIDUAL");
        modelo.addColumn("T_OTRAS_DEDU1");
        modelo.addColumn("T_OTRAS_DEDU2");
        modelo.addColumn("T_OTRAS_DEDU3");
        modelo.addColumn("T_PERCEP");
        modelo.addColumn("T_DED");
        modelo.addColumn("T_LIQUIDO");
    
        while (rs.next()) {
            Object[] filas = new Object[cantidadColumnas]; //Declarar un vector.
    
            for (int i = 0; i < cantidadColumnas; i++) {
                filas[i] = rs.getObject(i + 1); //Recorrer la columnas.
            }
            modelo.addRow(filas); //Añadimos las filas creadas
        }
    
        //cerramos la base de datos
        con.desconectar();
    
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println("Error: " + e);
    }
```

Comment: No es la respuesta: ¿No te suena más poner todo ese bloque SQL como un SP en la base de datos? Es más... mantenible

Answer (score 0):

Pasa que estás usando `executeQuery`, que espera que tu instrucción SQL retorne un resultSet. Eso no pasa con tu bloque de transacción; no hay ningún SELECT más allá de los que asignan valores a las variables declaradas. La salida de ese bloque es vacía, como si fuese un SP que no retornara nada.

Entonces, como entiendo que quieres obtener los datos en las variables `@RFC, @NOMBRE,...`, tienes que hacer un SELECT de esas variables. Que estén declaradas no significa que las estés pidiendo como salida de la consulta :)

```java
+ "--insertar los valores en la tabla ARCH_QUINZ\n"
+ "     insert into ARCH_QUINZ values (@RFC,@NOMBRE,@F_INGRESO,@ID_PUESTO,@ID_OFICINA,@ID_DTO,@ID_SUBD,@S_DIARIO,\n"
+ "     @DIAS_T_QNA,@H_EXT,@T_S_QNA,@T_H_EXTRAS,@T_CANASTA,@T_P_VAC,@T_P_DOM,@T_AGUINALDO,@T_R_UTILIDAD,@T_D_FEST,\n"
+ "     @T_BONO_PRODUCTIVIDAD,@T_OTROS_BONO1,@T_OTROS_BONO2,@T_OTROS_BONO3,@T_ISPT,@T_ISSSTE,@T_FOVISSTE,@T_C_SINDICAL,\n"
+ "     @T_PRESTAMO_INDIVIDUAL,@T_OTROS_DEDU1,@T_OTROS_DEDU2,@T_OTROS_DEDU3,@T_PERCEP,@T_DED,@T_LIQUIDO)\n"
+ "\n"
+ " commit transaction Nomina\n"
+ " \n"
+ " SELECT @RFC, @NOMBRE, @F_INGRESO, ..., @T_LIQUIDO;"
+ " end try\n"
```

PD. Tener ese bloque de transacción, con todo y los fin de línea, como un gran string Java, es difícil de mantener, de hacerle debug y de cualquier otra cosa que implique trabajar con él. Explora la posibilidad de volverlo un SP en la base de datos.